# multiple checkbox valiadation for any one in YII frame work for this example

Tags: yii

Hi can you please tell how can i validate the multiple checkbox any one is checked in yii framework

array('accept', 'required', 'requiredValue' => 1, 'message' => 'You should select alteast one')

Comment: validating checkbox atleast one is selected i have to validate for multiple checkbox please can you guys help me

Comment: Try using `CHTML::checkBoxList()` and make it required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these value are usually sent as arrays, I wrote an array validator for these cases once: https://github.com/schmunk42/p3extensions/blob/master/validators/P3ArrayValidator.php

Usage example:

```
array('accept',
  'ext.validators.P3ArrayValidator', 
  'min'=>1,
  'allowEmpty'=>false, 
  'message' => 'You should select at least one'
),
```

Comment: Not Useful for this qution, can please tell me with example to validate only check box

Comment: Hmm, I would say it does exactly what you need, see the updated usage example.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late reply.

But, I found a solution without installing any extension.

Take a hidden field with the same name [Checkboxes list field].

```
<?php echo $form->hiddenField($model,'categories');?>
```

Display a list of categories with name different from our field name (multiple checkboxes).

But, remember the 'class', and play with the class to save the values.

```
<?php 
echo CHtml::checkBoxList(
    'group',
    //you can pass the array here which you want to be pre checked 
    explode(',', trim($model->attributes['categories'], ',')),
    CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(),'id','name'),
    array('separator'=>'', 'template'=>'<tr><td style="width:5%;">{input}</td><td>{label}</td></tr>', 'class' => 'group')
);
?>
```

This way validation should work also, you get category ids as comma separated e.g. `[,1,2,6,]`

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $(".group").click(function(){
    var str = $('.group:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
    }).get().join();
    var groupCats = (str.length > 0) ? ','+str+',' : '';
    $('#ModelNAME_field').val(groupCats);
    // Get the 'ModelNAME_field' by viewing source of HTML of hidden field.
  });
});
</script>
```